# Can I force, via HTML, e-mail addresses not to appear underline and blue?

Tags: html, email

My HTML e-mail signature has my e-mail address. Can I force, via HTML, my address not to appear underline and blue in e-mail clients? GMail, Outlook, etc.?

Note that the decoration is added by the e-mail clients.

Comment: Using HTML alone No. using CSS yes.

Comment: @Nacereddine: Gmail's web client ignores `<style>` tags

Comment: @SLaks What about inline styles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define the styles of the a-tag as this:

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;" href="mailto:john@example.com">John</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah use inline style:

`<a style="text-decoration:none !important; color:black !important;" />`

Add `!important`, just to make sure

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you do not put the link (e.g. `<a/>` element) manually. It is the email client that shows the address as link.

To avoid this, you could use an alternative for ＠ symbol, as in http://lea.verou.me/about/, though I can't imagine the reason to do that in e-mail message anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with inline styles, like this:

```
<a href="http://blah.com" style="color:red;text-decoration:none">
  This text will have no underline and be red
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in GMail.

1. Use Mozilla Firefox
2. Install the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon.
3. Go to signature editing page
4. Add and link the email address. You will find it take the default underline and blue text.
5. Right click on it. Select "Inspect element"
6. You will find the raw HTML code over there. Select the email link. It will look like `<a href="mailto:address">address</a>`
7. Right click on it and select "New attribute..."
8. Name the new attribute `style` and put any CSS as its value. E.g. To change color and remove underline put `style="text-decoration:none;color:#ABCDEF"`
9. Save the signature!

You will find that you have the new looking signature email address link. Hope this helps.